# Python - Splitting List To Get Minimum & Maximum

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list with 2 elements each, the first element is the timestamp and the second is a cost, it's a list of 10, what i want to do is simply sort by minimum and maximum and display it's timestamp to see what time during the day the highest or the minimum cost occurred.

so something like this would be the max ['280.88000000'] but i want to know what time of the day this occurred so i would need the date ['280.88000000', 2019-04-13 13:42:00] , it doesn't need to be inside a list, it can be string or anything, just don't know how to do it.. here is the code i've tried.

```
import time
import datetime


timencost = [[1555232400000, '278.63000000'], [1555236000000, '278.80000000'], [1555239600000, '279.25000000'], [1555243200000, '278.16000000'], [1555246800000, '283.10000000'], [1555250400000, '279.85000000'], [1555254000000, '279.93000000'], [1555257600000, '280.88000000'], [1555261200000, '278.91000000'], [1555264800000, '280.75000000']]


minn = float(min([i[-1] for i in timencost]))

maxx = float(max([i[-1] for i in timencost]))

print(minn, maxx)

dates = [i[-2] for i in timencost]

print(dates) #???????

#this is where iam stuck...

print(minn, "date:", str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(dates/1000)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

how do i display the correct date next to my minimum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
import datetime

def by_price(e):
  return float(e[1])


timencost = [[1555232400000, '278.63000000'], [1555236000000, '278.80000000'], [1555239600000, '279.25000000'], [1555243200000, '278.16000000'], [1555246800000, '283.10000000'], [1555250400000, '279.85000000'], [1555254000000, '279.93000000'], [1555257600000, '280.88000000'], [1555261200000, '278.91000000'], [1555264800000, '280.75000000']]

sorted_timencost = sorted(timencost,key=by_price)

print('max: {} {} '.format(sorted_timencost[0][1],datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sorted_timencost[0][0]/1000)))

print('min: {} {} '.format(sorted_timencost[-1][1],datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sorted_timencost[-1][0]/1000)))
```

Output

```
max: 278.16000000 2019-04-14 12:00:00
min: 283.10000000 2019-04-14 13:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) directly by passing in a `key` argument that describes how you want to deal with the elements in question. The key should be a simple function, for example one that converts the correct index to float

```
max(timencost, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))  # max based on float of index 1 of each element

# same with min
min(timencost, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

Putting it together gives you something like:

```
import datetime

timencost = [[1555232400000, '278.63000000'], [1555236000000, '278.80000000'], [1555239600000, '279.25000000'], [1555243200000, '278.16000000'], [1555246800000, '283.10000000'], [1555250400000, '279.85000000'], [1555254000000, '279.93000000'], [1555257600000, '280.88000000'], [1555261200000, '278.91000000'], [1555264800000, '280.75000000']]

minn = min(timencost, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
maxx = max(timencost, key=lambda x: float(x[1]))

print("min", "date:", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(minn[0]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print("max", "date:", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(maxx[0]/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split up the list

```
# First turn those strings to numbers
timencost = [(x, float(y)) for x,y in timencost]

# Sort them by cost
timencost.sort(key=lambda e: e[1])
# Get the max and min entries
min_entry = timencost[0]
max_entry = timencost[-1]

# the entries have both the cost and the time, format the dates how you want
```